# Not finding the metadata window (F12) when using Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> (or right-click and select Go To Definition)  in Visual Studio on code I don't  have the source for, it should bring up a generated metadata file. (Very similar to the Code Definition Window)

This doesn't work when ReSharper (R#) is installed. After R# is installed, the Object Browser opens instead.

I've had this problem on several fresh installed computers, and at least since R# 3. (You'll see this works again when you disable R# and restart VS)

How can I get to the metadataview now?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can change ReSharper's F12 action by going to ReSharper -> Options... -> Tools -> External Sources and changing the order and selection of the External source data providers.

Credit and more details: http://blog.aheil.de/2009/12/27/resharper-5-0-can-visual-studio-2010-metadata-view/

Comment: I know! Great tip! And the bug in the opening question is fixed as wel in v5!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Although preferably edit it to include the info in the answer - the blog post might get removed one day.

Comment: @Jez, I have quickly updated the answer. Let me know what you think.